# How to install HTML5/JavaScript to Netbeans?

Tags: software-installation, html, programming, javascript

I installed the NetBeans Connector plugin to Chromium on my MacBook. That worked perfectly. I could create new projects in HTML5/Javascript.

I tried to do the same on my Linux Mint 18.3 computer. But there is no project HTML5/JavaScript to choose as a category when I am creating a new project.

Help please.

Comment: A silly question: have you activated HTML5 plugin?

Comment: @ajeh how do I do that?